# Angular extend JSON properties except for certain keys

Tags: json, angularjs, extend

I am using angular to extend the properties of a given JSON object however there are some attributes I don't want  _.extend  to accept

Example:

```
var myNewObj    =  { id:null, name: "david", age: 25}

var originalObj =  { id:55,   name: "david", age: 25, department: "sales"}

_.extend(myNewObj, originalObj);
```

Returns myNewObj with the "id" field populated as 55- This field should never be populated or overwritten

Answer (score 2):

As it seems you have lodash (or underscore) :

```
_.extend(myNewObj, _.omit(originalObj, 'id'));
```

This will assign to `myNewObj` the (own) properties of `originalObj`, **except the `id`**.

Answer (score 0):

use

`angular.extend`

Instead  `_extend`

Comment: My problem is not how to use extend, but how to make sure extend ignores specific attributes

Comment: See @michael-p-bazos answer. That does the trick. `Omit` will only take properties not specified there.